# TransferHandler on whole JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to handle `File Drops` from other applications.
Now I am at the point where I can differentiate between different `DataFlavors` and accept the right types.

Here is the source code I am working with:

```
private TransferHandler transferehandler = new TransferHandler(){
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }

            boolean copySupported = (MOVE & support.getSourceDropActions()) == MOVE;

            if (!copySupported) {
                return false;
            }

            support.setDropAction(MOVE);


        return true;
        }
```

This first part is setting up my canImport, to check if the File supports the `MOVE` option, and check if its a file.

```
@Override
        public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support){
            if(!canImport(support))
                return false;
             Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
             try {
                List<File> l = (List<File>) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                System.out.println(l);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
             return true;
        }
    };
```

Here is my implementation of the `importData` Method. For testing purpose, I am printing every file which is dragged onto the `Component` which has this `TransferHandler`.

By reading the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html) i only got to the point where I can handle drops from different `JPanels`.
But I actually want to create something like this:

[image: It should look like this]

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: And how about setting youd DnD handler directly to main top level container - the content pane? `JFramage.getContentPane()`

Comment: You cant set it directly to the `Content Pane`, but If you add it to the JFrame only the upper `bar` becomes droppable, in fact I could set the TransfereHandler to every single Component, but that would be ridiculous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can DnD on any child component (like I wrote in comment). You can drop both on Red (parent content pane) and Blue (child) components.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;


public class TransferableJFrame {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();

        f.setSize(1000, 1000);

        JPanel contentPane=new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.red);
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        contentPane.setTransferHandler(new MyTrasnferHandler());


        JPanel child=new JPanel();
        child.setOpaque(true);
        child.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        child.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (600,600));
        contentPane.add(child);
        f.setContentPane(contentPane);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }

    private static class MyTrasnferHandler extends TransferHandler{
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor[] transferFlavors) {
            System.out.println("we will drop here");
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
            System.out.println("Dropped");
            return super.importData(comp, t);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Iv just missed WCS Elazer (countrymate) VS Hydra to write you that example ;)

Comment: Oh man sorry to hear that ^^ But as simple as it sounds, it does its job! Maybe Oracle they should add this small info to their tutorial. A little sentence like: "If you add the Handler to the parent component, it also affects all child components". PS: Starcraft is a really good game but a little bit to fast for my taste :D

Comment: Well to be honest, they did. Glad I could help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html

Comment: Yes i misread `But you can also set a TransferHandler directly on a top-level container, such as JFrame and JDialog.` and thought that this would only affect the "outer" parts of the application like the title bar.